# Symfony Criteria Join unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, sql, join, symfony1, symfony-1.4

i'm trying to do a complex query with Criteria in a Symfony project using Propel ORM.

the query i want to make is, in human words:

```
Select from the 'interface' table the registers that: 
- 1 are associated with a process (with a link table)
- 2 have a name similat to $name
- 3 its destiny application's name is $apd (application accecible by foreign key)
- 4 its originapplication's name is $apo (application accecible by foreign key)
```

here the code i made, and not working:

```
    $c = new Criteria();
    $c->addJoin($linkPeer::CODIGO_INTERFASE,$intPeer::CODIGO_INTERFASE);       //1
    $c->add($linkPeer::CODIGO_PROCESONEGOCIO,$this->getCodigoProcesonegocio());//1
    if($name){                                                    
        $name = '%'.$name.'%';                                    //2
        $c->add($intPeer::NOMBRE_INTERFASE,$name,Criteria::LIKE); //2
    }
    if($apd){
        $apd = '%'.$apd.'%'; //3
        $c->addJoin($appPeer::CODIGO_APLICACION,$intPeer::CODIGO_APLICACION_DESTINO);//3
        $c->add($appPeer::NOMBRE_APLICACION,$apd,Criteria::LIKE); //3
    }
    if($apo){
        $apo = '%'.$apo.'%';//4
        $c->addJoin($appPeer::CODIGO_APLICACION,$intPeer::CODIGO_APLICACION_ORIGEN);//4
        $c->add($appPeer::NOMBRE_APLICACION,$apo,Criteria::LIKE);//4
    }
```

After that i did a `$c->toString()` to see the SQL generated and i saw that when i send only an $apd value, the SQL is correct, when i send an $apo value too. But when i send both, only the $apo `AND` apears on the SQL.

I guess its because the $c->add(...) call is the same with a distinct parameter, but not sure at all. Is this the error? What is the best way to generate my query correctly?

Thank you very much for your time! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's overriding the previous call as the Criteria object only stores one condition per field. The solution is to create 2 or more separate Criterion objects and mix them into the Criteria object:

```
//something like this
$cron1 = $criteria->getNewCriterion();
$cron1->add($appPeer::NOMBRE_APLICACION,$apo,Criteria::LIKE);//4
$criteria->add($cron);
//and the same with the other criterion
```

However, it would be much easier to upgrade to Propel15+, where you work on the Query class level, and multiple restrictions on the same field don't override each other.

Hope this helps,
Daniel